# Beautiful Soup - Get the tag containing exactly the indicated classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the tag with Beautiful Soup containing exactly the 4 classes: tf-r r-tab r-group-1 cell-minor shown

```
<tr> 
    ...
    <td class="tf-r r-tab r-group-1 cell-minor shown">9</td>
    ....
</tr>
```

I tried with:

```
for td in tr.find_all(('td'), class_=['tf-r', 'r-tab', 'r-group-1' 'shown']):
    print(td)
```

but it takes td's with atleast one of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for td in tr.find_all("td", {"class": ["tf-r r-tab r-group-1 cell-minor shown"]}):
    print(td)
```

**Or**

Using `css selectors`:

```
tr.select('td.tf-r.r-tab.r-group-1.shown')
```

Comment: assuming all the td will have classes in this order only

Comment: Tried this both methods before and I get 0 results.

Comment: To be more specific it's the Death column from dotabuff.com:
https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/5298045165

Comment: @MariusPantazi I tested this solution and it works with the example you provided. I also reviewed in the web page and I didn't find any tag with class="tf-r r-tab r-group-1 cell-minor shown"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out. The last tag was causing the problem. I don't know why.

```
for td in tr.find_all("td", {"class": ["tf-r r-tab r-group-1 cell-minor"]}):
    print(td)
```

Thanks for the help @Pygirl.